# How to update helm3 in microk8s?

Tags: kubernetes-helm, microk8s

I have this helm3 version:

```
microk8s helm3 version

version.BuildInfo{Version:"v3.0.2", GitCommit:"19e47ee3283ae98139d98460de796c1be1e3975f", GitTreeState:"clean", GoVersion:"go1.13.5"}
```

How can I update to a new version?

Comment: Use external Helm, see here for details: https://worklifenotes.com/2020/01/22/how-to-make-microk8s-work-with-helm/

Answer (score 0):

According to https://microk8s.io/docs/upgrading,

---

**IMPORTANT NOTE:** Add-ons, unless specified otherwise in the documentation, will NOT be upgraded as part of a MicroK8s upgrade. Currently, the most effective way to upgrade these add-ons is to use microk8s disable  and then re-enable them. Please make sure to read the release notes for specific details referring to add-ons before upgrading.

---

I did this for helm3 (after switching channels on the microk8s snap to latest/stable and refreshing), and helm3 went from v3.0.2 to v3.5.